# Web deployment task failed. (Web Deploy detected insufficient space on disk.)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have Azure Free Tier Web Application. I just updated my nuget packages, and added some views.

When I try to publish via Visual Studio 2015, I am getting following error:

> Error Web deployment task failed. (Web Deploy detected insufficient
>   space on disk. Learn more at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_DISK_SPACE.)

When I check Kudu console it is showing my directories as:

> D:\home usage: 1,024 MB total; 0 MB free
>
> d:\local usage: 500 MB total; 492 MB free

So, in D:\Home, most of the space taken by **.nuget** folder. Probably error is coming from this side. However, since my webapp/bin folder has required binaries, do I even need this folder? Can I manually delete it or disable Azure to host this folder at all?

Last case scenario, should I upgrade my app to go out of free tier? I do not want to do that, since this is my side project, and I am progressing on it slowly, it is not ready for production yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error, it looks like you are deploying via WebDeploy (e.g. from VS) and not from git. In that scenario, I don't think you should have a `d:\home\.nuget` folder at all. Could it be left over from previous things you did, maybe with git? If so, you can definitely delete it. It is not used at runtime.